# Unable to find Walmart search bar element?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm creating a bot that would require Selenium to click on the search bar for Walmart to input the name of a product and then search it. The problem is no matter what I use

[Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/)

```
    class="flex flex-auto items-center relative" or class="b--none f5 flex-auto lh-solid sans-serif br-pill" or ID = "header-input-search"
```

it doesn't seem to be able to find the search bar to input the product name to search. The error code I get is:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

```
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/")

time.sleep(4)

searchW = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".b--none f5 flex-auto lh-solid sans-serif br-pill")

searchW.send_keys(product) 

searchW.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:    
    itemWTitle = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,(".absolute w-100 h-100 z-1 hide-sibling-opacity"))

    print(itemWTitle.text)

    itemWPrice = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,(".b black f5 mr1 mr2-xl lh-copy f4-l"))

    print(itemWPrice.text[0:7])

except:
    print("Couldn't find product at Walmart")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using xpath and the searching for the name attribute

```
driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/")

time.sleep(4)

searchW = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")

searchW.send_keys(product) 

searchW.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

---

#### Update

The actual reason why you cannot find it is because walmart is detecting that you are using an automation tool and needlessly forces you to validate a bunch of repetitive captchas and other tests.

Comment: Just tried "searchW = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='q']")" still nothing unfortunately. Very odd I feel like it's something very simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: it is because walmart.com has anti-automation measures in place @dualist

Comment: @Dualists  try actually performing this in an interactive python session using an actual webdriver and browser... you will see that walmart detects that you are using an automation tool and forces you to do a bunch of captchas and other verification methods

Comment: Ah I noticed that but I thought if I just do the captcha everytime then it would work until I have to do it again. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: I mean.  I am sure someone somewhere has come up with a means to bypass it.  But nothing that is well known or easily implemented... These tests are specifically designed to keep people from doing exactly what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of accessing that page without being blocked (of course, if your IP isn't already blacklisted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t

import undetected_chromedriver as uc


options = uc.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,720")

browser = uc.Chrome(options=options)

actions = ActionChains(browser)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

url = 'https://www.walmart.com/'

browser.get(url)
t.sleep(5)
searchbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[aria-label="Search"]')))
actions.move_to_element(searchbox).perform()
t.sleep(1)
searchbox.click()
searchbox.send_keys('AR-15')
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

To my pleasant surprise, they stopped selling the real thing. Maybe there is hope after all.. but I digress. For Selenium documentation, you can visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/
And for undetected_chromedriver, see https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/